# What icons does Xubuntu use?

Tags: xubuntu, icons, xfce, icon-themes

I like the Xubuntu default icons, but I'm not using Ubuntu. Can I download the icons to make my xfce look like Xubuntu?

Comment: note: if you are using Ubuntu with the xfce desktop, you now have Xubuntu

Comment: I'm actually using Fedora. I was able to download the `xubuntu-artwork` package and move the icons folder into `~/.icons`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Flavour-specific themes, icons, etc., are grouped under the corresponding `-artwork` package, which in turn may depend on various icon packages, walppaper packages, etc. For Xubuntu, that would be [`xubuntu-artwork`](https://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/xubuntu-artwork), which depends on:

```
plymouth-theme-xubuntu-logo
plymouth-theme-xubuntu-text
shimmer-themes
xubuntu-icon-theme
xubuntu-wallpapers
```

So, you probably need to install `xubuntu-icon-theme`.